# Get TimeZone from internet in Android

Tags: android, timezone, utc

I am trying to get time from the device but it returns incorrect time if I change my timezone (Because of the timezone). Is there any way to fetch timezone from the internet so that If a user changes its device timezone it should show the actual real time.

BTW I am using the true time library to get real UTC time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a publicly available API for this. I use http://ip-api.com/json go thorugh [documention](http://ip-api.com/docs/) before implementation. However if you want you can use other APIs. As I am sure there are many.